# Narrow union type based on literal property value

Tags: typescript

I think my use-case is fairly common; I'm trying to type an HTTP response object such that the body is only reliably defined if the status code is exactly 200. I'd like to return the object as a type `ResponseType` such that people who call my function that returns it can do e.g.:

```js
function doSomething<T extends {property: "value"}>(r: ResponseType<T>): void {
    if (r.status === 200) {
        // r.body has the type 'T & {property: "value"}' here
        console.log(r.body.property);
    } else {
        // r.body has the type 'undefined' here
        console.log("no body");
    }
}
```

So, to accomplish this I've tried:

```js
type ResponseType<T> = {
    body: T;
    status: 200;
} | {
    body: undefined;
    status: Exclude<number, 200>;
};
```

But that doesn't work, because `number` isn't a union type, and since `number` isn't assignable to `200`, but `200` is assignable to `number`, this winds up being equivalent to

```js
type ResponseType<T> = {
    body: T;
    status: 200;
} | {
    body: undefined;
    status: number;
};
```

and because checking the value of a `number` doesn't narrow it to the constant you're checking against (even if you were to do e.g. `if (resp.status === 200 as const)` or `if (resp.status === 200 as 200)`), this is in turn equivalent to

```js
// requires --noUnusedParameters to be 'false'
type ResponseType<T> = {
    body: undefined;
    status: number;
}
```

since `200` and `number` are different types - even if one is assignable to the other - I feel strongly that there has to be a way to tell TypeScript that it's safe to infer the type of an object's property based on which of those types another property is, without requiring callers to write a run-time type guard check. But how do I do it?

Comment: Typo? `ResponseType` => `ResponseBody`?

Comment: I think you'll have to use a type guard for this.

Comment: "typo?" yes it was, fixed

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of other way to achieve what you want. Here is my solution.

```js
type T200Response<T> = {
    body: T;
    status: 200;
}

type TNon200Response= {
    body: undefined;
    status: number;
}

function is200Response<T>(response: TResponse<T>): response is T200Response<T> {
    return response.status === 200;
}

type TResponse<T> = T200Response<T> | TNon200Response;

function doSomething<T extends {property: "value"}>(r: TResponse<T>): void {
    // is200Response to hints TS which type is it. 
    // If this function return true then TS will assume r is T200Response<T> within the if clause
    if (is200Response<T>(r)) {
        // r.body has the type 'T & {property: "value"}' here

        r.body; // Mouseover body you will see T
        console.log(r.body.property);
    } else {
        r.body; // Mouseover body you will see undefined

        // r.body has the type 'undefined' here
        console.log("no body");
    }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTABgQJQgZzAewHZogHhgD4oBeKAbwFgAoKeqAI0wBMQAuWAbloajWABDYAFc0nRAh40AvrVqhIsAHI5JqDDjzlqdBszacR2FhABmAS2wQW0vgOFjO2EQFtGEAE7S5NWmeMAY2ALHCgLNHV0LFwCYgAKT2itCE4YDRi8QiIASk4kzVjwtFgowqziSl4GJNFPbCgCzIgAOgdREtIuqEkfeRpFaHTk2OyyUqQMlLGAHxU1SZG8aX8gkLCWTABlTFcIYAALKwBzQigIAA9gCBMSijBPTEhPUE4AIgA3QQAbEQg3mRERJpKajYh5KAfTAWFhVPT0CxmKDxCJlZrZRI5HJwvh8AD0eMaLQMICgB0EJUO0EGUAA5DAoAAySgPJ5eV5QT4-P4A2lkrwQfq4mrE1ggLhQAlQACymDEEEwHy8TDFUBAcqgAHcLN9vvwIENqsLAlpMN9Wt9MMdEqK2C1Wc9QDk7AwZOdvngccKiSSJVLZfLFcqSWqNdrdfroMZTJZrCwhd6pZ5baTyZSDtTwNBadHzFYbHyM0kjbiTbgzRarfE3thMCq2G9nSXfDIgA